# Get comma-separated set of values from table where another reference value on another table appears twice (or more)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Suppose the following DB setup in SQL Server 2014:

```
DECLARE @MATERIAL TABLE (ID int, CODE varchar(30));

INSERT @MATERIAL (ID, CODE) VALUES
(1, 'D3033MBBY'),
(2, 'D3033MBTY'),
(3, '011130-01'),
(4, '011130-04C'),
(5, '021002'),
(6, '021017-B'),
(7, '021134-01'),
(8, '021135-01'),
(9, '021955-01'),
(10, '3LS91101-550'),
(11, 'D3049MBRB'),
(12, 'EF0118'),
(13, 'FV8130'),
(14, 'FY7009'),
(15, 'H05802'),
(16, 'D3033MRTE');

DECLARE @SUBSTITUTE TABLE (ID int, ITEID int, SUBSTITUTECODE varchar(100));

INSERT @SUBSTITUTE (ID, ITEID, SUBSTITUTECODE) VALUES
(5232, 1, '191045762418'),
(5442, 2, '191045762418'),
(6435, 3, '5206432380030'),
(6573, 4, '5206432380030'),
(6582, 5, '5206432357131'),
(6683, 6, '5206432369486'),
(7332, 7, '5206432380610'),
(7482, 8, '5206432380818'),
(7721, 9, '5206432346029'),
(7831, 10, '5205172116350'),
(8034, 11, '191045480992'),
(8184, 12, '4061622759543'),
(8284, 13, '4062058577497'),
(8573, 14, '4064039588089'),
(9438, 15, '4064048672519'),
(9746, 16, '191045762418');

SELECT sub.SUBSTITUTECODE
FROM @SUBSTITUTE AS sub
INNER JOIN @MATERIAL AS prod ON prod.ID = sub.ITEID
GROUP BY sub.SUBSTITUTECODE
HAVING COUNT(sub.SUBSTITUTECODE) > 1;
```

I would like to create a query that would produce the following resultset:

| CODES | SUBSTITUTECODE |
| --- | --- |
| D3033MBBY,D3033MBTY,D3033MRTE | 191045762418 |
| 011130-01,011130-04C | 5206432380030 |

In other words, I'd like to get a comma-separated set of `CODE`s in `@MATERIAL` where there are duplicate `SUBSTITUTECODE` references for those records in table `@SUBSTITUTE`

Indirectly, I can find the `CODE`s that correspond to those duplicate `SUBSTITUTECODE`s with the following query:

```
SELECT prod.CODE, sub.SUBSTITUTECODE
FROM @SUBSTITUTE AS sub
INNER JOIN @MATERIAL AS prod ON prod.ID = sub.ITEID
WHERE sub.SUBSTITUTECODE IN (SELECT sub.SUBSTITUTECODE
    FROM @SUBSTITUTE AS sub
    INNER JOIN @MATERIAL AS prod ON prod.ID = sub.ITEID
    GROUP BY sub.SUBSTITUTECODE
    HAVING COUNT(sub.SUBSTITUTECODE) > 1)
```

Working fiddle for the above case can be found [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=ea00cfadc63d2b04918cca4aaf369a13).

Please note that the full case of this scenario runs on SQL Server 2014.

TIA

Comment: I've managed to get this far as it is shown in the working fiddle. I mean, I'm able to get a list of the `SUBSTITUTECODE`s with duplicate entries! I can't add the column with the comma-separated values of the products that correspond to each of those.

Comment: @DaleK I added more info in my question. I'm able to get the `CODES` as well as the `SUBSTITUTECODE`s that correspond to them in separate rows, and with an indirect query, meaning a query where I combine two queries in one with the use of `IN` clause... But I bet there is another solution using simply some type of `JOIN` clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice starting fiddle, thanks! If we just take what you already have and put it in a CTE, we can write a standard string aggregation around it:

```
;WITH subs AS 
(
  SELECT prod.CODE, sub.SUBSTITUTECODE
  FROM @SUBSTITUTE AS sub
  INNER JOIN @MATERIAL AS prod ON prod.ID = sub.ITEID
  WHERE sub.SUBSTITUTECODE IN (SELECT sub.SUBSTITUTECODE
    FROM @SUBSTITUTE AS sub
    INNER JOIN @MATERIAL AS prod ON prod.ID = sub.ITEID
    GROUP BY sub.SUBSTITUTECODE
    HAVING COUNT(sub.SUBSTITUTECODE) > 1)
)
SELECT CODES = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CODE 
  FROM subs AS s2 WHERE s2.SUBSTITUTECODE = subs.SUBSTITUTECODE
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,''),
    SUBSTITUTECODE FROM subs
  GROUP BY SUBSTITUTECODE;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=01c6d7e580857f490775bf99561a87f3)

But we can simplify this code slightly, most importantly to avoid referencing both tables *twice*, like this:

```
;WITH subs AS
(
  SELECT s.ITEID, s.SUBSTITUTECODE, m.CODE, 
    c = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.SUBSTITUTECODE)
  FROM @SUBSTITUTE AS s
  INNER JOIN @MATERIAL AS m
  ON m.ID = s.ITEID
)
SELECT CODES = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CODE
  FROM subs AS s2 WHERE s2.SUBSTITUTECODE = subs.SUBSTITUTECODE
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,''),
    SUBSTITUTECODE
  FROM subs 
  WHERE c > 1 
  GROUP BY SUBSTITUTECODE;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=24b54b09353121e974e59b8015b0838c)

Note that on more modern versions of SQL Server (2017+), `STRING_AGG()` makes this much easier:

```
SELECT CODES = STRING_AGG(m.CODE, ','), s.SUBSTITUTECODE
  FROM @SUBSTITUTE AS s
  INNER JOIN @MATERIAL AS m
  ON m.ID = s.ITEID
  GROUP BY s.SUBSTITUTECODE
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5edb4b8e63d3955ada67d6be42f30f75)

Comment: I think I'll go with your solution (the simplified one) as it's much clearer to someone not at such an expert level as you are, to understand what's going on, instead of blindly copying your solution and pasting it in their real situation. Thank you so much for this!

Comment: Yup, unfortunately I don't have control over the running version of SQL server. Im only building this bridge to get a sync service running between their desktop merchandise app and a new website!

Comment: @Faye no problem, I think conceptually it can be a lot easier to just put everything inside the `STUFF()` out of your mind as "this is an expression that concatenates strings together." I have memorized the syntax but I don't really think about the underlying mechanics much anymore. The CTE gets the joined rows and provides a count _based on the column that has duplicates_ so we know how to filter. Then if you remove what's going on inside `STUFF()` (concatenate all the material codes matching this sub code), it's just select from the CTE where the count > 1.

Comment: `text()[1]` is faster than `.[1]`, see for example https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/193323/220697

Comment: @Charlieface It's true but other improvements (like upgrading) would have much more of an effect. :-) Also good luck teaching this muscle memory to use `text()` instead of `.`. You may as well ask me to start using Windows again. :-)

Comment: @Charlieface also FWIW I tried several variations to match the syntax from that answer and [couldn't get it to work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=24b54b09353121e974e59b8015b0838c). As an uncle used to tell me: steak's 5 cents a pound when you're out of steak.

Comment: `FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]'` you missed off `('')` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=6ebc1ceb8a011cf5809aea53d04ceaa3

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using SQL Server 2014, you can't use [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Here is the solution using `FOR XML PATH`

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT prod.CODE, sub.SUBSTITUTECODE, 
           c = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY sub.SUBSTITUTECODE)
    FROM   @SUBSTITUTE AS sub
           INNER JOIN @MATERIAL AS prod ON prod.ID = sub.ITEID
),
CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM   CTE
    WHERE  c > 1
)
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + CODE 
              FROM CTE2 x 
              WHERE x.SUBSTITUTECODE = c.SUBSTITUTECODE 
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''),
       SUBSTITUTECODE
FROM   CTE2 c
GROUP BY SUBSTITUTECODE
```

Comment: This works great! I only wonder if there would be any simpler way of writing the query without using two temp tables...

Comment: @FayeD. What temp tables? The two table variables where you stored your data? The two CTEs (which are far simpler than the query you have now)? Something else?

Comment: Yup, by temp tables I mean the two CTEs defined with the `WITH` expression.

Comment: @Faye you're going to have a real hard time doing this without table expressions like subqueries or CTEs. I think the number of CTEs in a query isn't the thing you should use to evaluate how clear or effective it is. :-)